# SQL parameters for upper case single letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Title seems confusing but the question is simple:
I made a column in TblPersonel called sex, this column must only allow one letter: M, W, or null (man, woman or null) but it can only be uppercase and only allowed to be that or null.

What I have is this:

```
ALTER TABLE TblPersonel
ADD Sex varchar(1);
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Comment: Usually is `Gender` and is `M` or `F` ... not going into https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25826/how-can-i-deal-with-diverse-gender-identities-in-user-profiles

Comment: Also, it makes more sense for this field to be `char(1)`, not `varchar(1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE TblPersonel
  ADD CONSTRAINT ch CHECK(Sex COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 IN ('M', 'W') )
```

Comment: field name should respect the original case... you know, in case the DB collation is case sensitive ;)

Comment: Thank you! What's the Latin_General_BIN2 for btw?

Comment: @GerrittenNapel - This is collation, which defines comparison "rules" for that column in this case. run this query and you see description for this collation:  `select name, COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage') as Code_Page, description
from sys.fn_HelpCollations()
where name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this following:

```
ALTER TABLE TblPersonel
  ADD CONSTRAINT CK_TblPersonel_Sex CHECK(Sex IN ('M', 'W'))
```